# Create a list with 6 items

Tags: python, list, syntax

I need to create a list of 6 elements I do it through a loop so that it does it with each row of data inside the array **ingreso_datos**.

In doing so I have created a list called **counters** within which there is another list of 6 elements, but what I am looking for is simply to create a list of 6 elements.

image that describes my problem:

[image: image that describes my problem]

I am still understanding the syntax in lists, python is my first programming language, I appreciate the feedback, regards

```
ingreso_datos = [[ 1,    'C',    28,    29,    30,    19,    20,     21,      0,      0,      0,    2.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [ 2,    'C',    31,    32,    33,    22,    23,      24,    4.5,      0,    4.5,    2.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [ 3,    'C',    34,    35,    36,    25,    26,      27,    9.5,      0,    9.5,    2.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [ 4,    'C',    19,    20,    21,    10,    11,      12,      0,    2.5,      0,      5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [ 5,    'C',    22,    23,    24,    13,    14,     15,    4.5,    2.5,    4.5,      5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [ 6,    'C',    25,    26,    27,     6,    17,      18,    9.5,    2.5,    9.5,      5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [ 7,    'C',    10,    11,    12,     1,     2,       3,      0,      5,      0,    7.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [ 8,    'C',    13,    14,    15,     4,     5,       6,    4.5,      5,    4.5,    7.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [ 9,    'C',    16,    17,    18,     7,     8,       9,    9.5,      5,    9.5,    7.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [10,    'B',    19,    20,    21,    22,    23,      24,      0,    2.5,    4.5,    2.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [11,    'B',    22,    23,    24,    25,    26,      27,    4.5,    2.5,    9.5,    2.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [12,    'B',    10,    11,    12,    13,    14,      15,      0,      5,    4.5,      5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [13,    'B',    13,    14,    15,    16,    17,      18,    4.5,      5,    9.5,      5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [14,    'B',     1,     2,     3,     4,     5,       6,      0,    7.5,    4.5,    7.5,    'HEB',    200],
                 [15,    'B',     4,     5,     6,     7,     8,       9,    4.5,    7.5,    9.5,    7.5,    'HEB',    200]] 


for i  in range(len(ingreso_datos)):

    counters = []

    counters.append([ingreso_datos[i][2], ingreso_datos[i][3], ingreso_datos[i][4],
                     ingreso_datos[i][5], ingreso_datos[i][6], ingreso_datos[i][7]])
```

Comment: You are append a new list to `counters` and not 6 items

Comment: With this code you will only ever retrieve the data from record 15. This is because every time it loops you are creating a new 'counters' list, which would be empty. 

If you really want to append, you should create the empty list outside of your for loop.

Comment: Move  `counters[]` before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current structure, try using `.extend` instead of `.append`. Try the below:

```
counters.extend([ingreso_datos[i][2], ingreso_datos[i][3], ingreso_datos[i][4],
                     ingreso_datos[i][5], ingreso_datos[i][6], ingreso_datos[i][7]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution has been very simple, I will take it into account for my learning, best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract elements 2-7 in every row of ingreso_datos you can write

```
counters = []
for i in range(len(ingresso_datos)):
    counters.append(ingresso_datos[i][2:8])
```

Now counters[0] will be the values 2-7 in the first row, counters[1] will be the values in the second row and so on. A more compact (and much faster) way to do the same thing is

```
counters = [ingresso_datos[i][2:8] for i in range(len(ingresso_datos))]
```

This is called a list generator, and if you keep using python you might as well get comfy with them :) If you want *all* the 2-7 values in *one* list (not a list of lists) you can use .extend as proposed or:

```
counters = [x for x in ingresso_datos[i][2:8] for i in range(len(ingresso_datos))]
```

which is in "long" form would be a double for loop:

```
counters = []
for i in range(len(ingresso_datos)):
   for x in ingresso_datos[i][2:8]:
       counters.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you want is like this.

```
counter = []
for x in range(2,8):
   counter.append(ingreso_datos[x][0])
```

this should return [3,4,5,6,7,8], where every value is received from every first index from list in ingreso_datos.